# create new table row after every n-th iteration with jQuery JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON variable:

```
{
  "Baby Wrap": {
    "img": "babywrap.jpg",
    "price": "150"
  },
  "BMW": {
    "img": "blackbmw.jpg",
    "price": "32,000"
  },
  "Samsung Galaxy S8": {
    "img": "galaxy.jpg",
    "price": "600"
  },
  "Motorcycle": {
    "img": "moto.jpg",
    "price": "37,000"
  },
  "Washer/Dryer": {
    "img": "washdry.jpg",
    "price": "1,300"
  },
  "Shoes (Women)": {
    "img": "shoes.jpg",
    "price": "350"
  },
  "Watch": {
    "img": "watch.jpg",
    "price": "430"
  },
  "Audi (2DR)": {
    "img": "whiteaudi2dr.jpg",
    "price": "38,000"
  }
}
```

And some jQuery:

```
var shopitems = JSON object;
var items = $.parseJSON(shopitems);
  $.each(items, function(k,v) {
    $("#shop").append('<tr><td>' + k + '</td></tr>');
  });
```

The 'k' values in this case are the names of the items ('Baby Wrap','BMW',etc). The 'v' values are the information attached (v.img,v.price). The code above makes every entry a new row (Right now I'm just printing out the item name). I want a table with 3 columns and as many rows as needed to fit the data.

Comment: What are expected results? Aren't you wanting table columns for this?

Comment: You need to show expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing with the idea from @MarkoMackic and came up with this:

```
 var i = 0;
 var items = $.parseJSON(shopitems);
 $("#shop").append('<tr>');
 $.each(items, function(k,v) {
  if (i%3 == 0) {
    $("#shop").append('</tr><tr>');
  }

  $("#shop").append('<td>' + k + '</td>');

  i++;
 });
```

This does what I wanted (sorry if I was unclear @charlietfl). It creates a three-column, n-row table to display the data.

Comment: you can't append a `<td>` directly to `<table>` and you can't appendclosing tag to dom the same way you would do in a code editor. Elements are added to dom as whole elements only

Comment: apparently you can append <td> directly to <table> because I did it. The same goes for the end tags.

Comment: doesn't mean it will work cross browser ... it's not valid html. As for the end tags...they are not doing what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
var i = 0;
var n = 3;
var shopitems = JSON object;
var items = $.parseJSON(shopitems);
  $.each(items, function(k,v) {
    i++;
    if(i%n == 0){
       $("#shop").append('<tr><td>' + k + '</td></tr>');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through `object` you can get the `index` of each key-value pair like:

```js
var shopitems = {
  "Baby Wrap": {
    "img": "babywrap.jpg",
    "price": "150"
  },
  "BMW": {
    "img": "blackbmw.jpg",
    "price": "32,000"
  },
  "Samsung Galaxy S8": {
    "img": "galaxy.jpg",
    "price": "600"
  },
  "Motorcycle": {
    "img": "moto.jpg",
    "price": "37,000"
  },
  "Washer/Dryer": {
    "img": "washdry.jpg",
    "price": "1,300"
  },
  "Shoes (Women)": {
    "img": "shoes.jpg",
    "price": "350"
  },
  "Watch": {
    "img": "watch.jpg",
    "price": "430"
  },
  "Audi (2DR)": {
    "img": "whiteaudi2dr.jpg",
    "price": "38,000"
  }
}

var items = shopitems;
var keys = Object.keys(items);
$.each(items, function(key, value) {
  var index = keys.indexOf(key);
  console.log(index, key)
  //$("#shop").append('<tr><td>' + key + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did not know about the Object.keys() method. I will definitely keep that in mind, maybe even change to that. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner loop of each sub object to complete each row.

```js
var shopitems = getData();

$.each(shopitems, function(k, v) {
   // start row and first cell from main property name
  var $tr = $('<tr>').append($('<td>', { text: k }));
  // loop over other properties for this row adding cells to row
  $.each(v, function(prop, val) {
    // image or text?
    var cellContent = prop === 'img' ? $('<img>', {src: val}) : val;
    $tr.append($('<td>').html(cellContent ));
  });
  // append whole row
  $("#shop").append($tr);
});

function getData() {
  return {
    "Baby Wrap": {
      "img": "babywrap.jpg",
      "price": "150"
    },
    "BMW": {
      "img": "blackbmw.jpg",
      "price": "32,000"
    },
    "Samsung Galaxy S8": {
      "img": "galaxy.jpg",
      "price": "600"
    },
    "Motorcycle": {
      "img": "moto.jpg",
      "price": "37,000"
    },
    "Washer/Dryer": {
      "img": "washdry.jpg",
      "price": "1,300"
    },
    "Shoes (Women)": {
      "img": "shoes.jpg",
      "price": "350"
    },
    "Watch": {
      "img": "watch.jpg",
      "price": "430"
    },
    "Audi (2DR)": {
      "img": "whiteaudi2dr.jpg",
      "price": "38,000"
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="shop"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var shopitems = JSON object;
var items = $.parseJSON(shopitems);
  $.each(items, function(k,v) {
    $("#shop").append('<tr><td>' + k + '</td><td>'+v.img+'</td><td>'+v.price+'</td></tr>');
  });
```